# Замена слова без replace

Tags: javascript

Как можно при помощи javascript заменить слово в тексте, не используя `replace`?

```
var text = "Этот трактат по теории этики был очень популярен в эпоху Возрождения";
```

Здесь нужно заменить слово "теории" на "практика".

Comment: приведите пример текста, и пример результата для него. А так же было бы не плохо указать чем не нравится `replace`

Comment: отредактируйте свой вопрос и вставьте в него этот фрагмент кода. Под вопросом есть кнопка "править".

Comment: var text = "Этот трактат по теории этики был очень популярен в эпоху Возрождения"; ну и здесь заменить слово "теории" на "практики"

Comment: в приведенном куске текста - нет слова "теория".

Comment: извините поправил)) имел ввиду "теории"

Comment: что не так с `replace`? почему нужно именно без него?

Comment: с replace все так, просто прохожу обучение по js и поставили задачу заменить слово не использую replace

Comment: почитайте, раз обучаетесь про `split()` / `join()`

Comment: Спасибо! буду вникать

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 10):

В качестве простой замены метода `replace` можно использовать пару методов [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) и [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

В таком виде:

```
str.split('подстрока которую заменить').join('строка на которую заменить');
```

Пример:

```js
var text = "test 1, test 2, test 3, test 4, test 5, test 6";

document.body.innerHTML = text + '<br/>'+
 
  text.split('test').join('newTest');
```

Comment: Спасибо! то что надо)

Comment: не додумался бы так))

Comment: @Yaroslav если вам был дан правильный ответ, отметьте его галкой.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, а как бы додумался? можешь соседним ответом опубликовать

Comment: Кстати насчет "простой" вы погорячились. Это отличная реализация `replace_all` которого в JavaScript нету (если без регэкспов). Рекомендую дописать чем все-таки отличается `str.replace('a', 'b');` от `str.split('a').join('b');`

Comment: @tutankhamun, feel free to change :-)

Comment: @tutankhamun, под простой имелось именно то, что с регулярками при таком подходе не так же как с replace получится, хотя `split` так же поддерживает регулярное выражение в качестве первого параметра

Answer (score 3):

Для разнообразия также можно произвести замену с помощью `indexOf()` и `substring()`. Точнее, это уже больше не "замена" а *"копировать/вырезать/вставить"*, но тоже работает.

```js
function replace(str, find, word) {
  var result = str, i = 0, len = find.length;
  while (len) {
    i = result.indexOf(find, i);
    if (i == -1) {
      break;
    }
    result = result.substring(0, i) + word + result.substring(i + len);
    i += len;
  }
  return result;
}

var newStr = replace("Этот трактат по теории этики", "по теории", "на практике");
console.log(newStr); // Этот трактат на практике этики
```

Comment: стоило бы результат `indexOf` сохранять :-) кстати, если менять на то же самое значение - то цикл никогда не закончится :)

Comment: @Grundy да ) бесконечный `while` можем бонусом получить. Дополнил :)

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich Сомнительный бонус :) Я позволил себе немного исправить ваш ответ

Comment: @tutankhamun, как-то не очень исправил :-) `len` не меняется смысл его в `while` проверять?

Comment: @Grundy если `find` будет пустым, цикл зациклится. Получится: одни грабли убрал, другие положил